# Juniper 802.3ad Link between Switch and Router 3x link issue

Tags: router, switch, juniper

We have a live 20Gbps link between our switch and router and we are trying to add another 10Gbps link to the LAG, we've changed all the settings on both end to add the third interface to the LAG yet it still shows 20Gbps no matter what we do. Does anyone have any insight what would cause the 802.3ad interface to not add the 3rd 10Gbps link?

Comment: This might be a limitation of either the switch or the router you are using. If you would care to publish the model numbers, it would be easy to check.

Comment: It's an MX240 router and a EX 6200 Switch

Comment: Try enabling tracing to see what is happening during negotiation. See https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos/topics/usage-guidelines/interfaces-configuring-aggregated-ethernet-lacp.html